# Why am I getting status:undefined from Chargebee API method validateVat?

Tags: javascript, validation, response, chargebee

I'm trying to user their VAT validation method with their script, but even when running their example I'm getting the same response:
https://www.chargebee.com/checkout-portal-docs/eu-vat-validation-function.html#integration

```
let cbInstance = Chargebee.getInstance();
  charegbeeInstance.load('functions').then(() => {
    const payload = {
          country: "DE",
          vat_number: "811569869",
        }
    cbInstance.vat.validateVat(payload).then(data => {
      // Your code here
    }).catch(err => {
      // Your code here
    })
  });
```

I'm always getting `{status: undefined}` as result. But the API is responding because If if don't send for example `var_number` I get the expected error from missing params.

Anyone with an idea what's happening or I'm missing something? Thanks!

Playground with mentioned case: https://jsfiddle.net/r27panuv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! VAT validation needed to be enabled in the admin panel. The documentation is missing that.